# How to remove the focus border of a CheckBox in C# Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, focus, border

Tried most properties and did not manage to completely disable the focus of a checkbox in visual studio. Does anyone know how to do it?

I am using a System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox object. I am using an image as background and when the CheckBox is in  focused state a border is drawn, which makes the background image look pretty bad. So I want to get rid of it...

EDIT: Adding a picture to clarify the intention of this question...

[image]

The user can tap "TAB" and click on the object to see it displayed as focused.
That was a problem for me since it made the GUI look simply terrible.

Comment: Is this WPF or WinForms?

Comment: What do you mean by border? Focus cue? Also winforms or wpf?

Comment: Could you make a screenshot? I'm not sure if I understand your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code for the CheckBox control that takes care of the painting is very elaborate, shared with Button and RadioButtion, supporting many styles.  It cannot be overridden, the involved classes and methods are all *internal*.

But luckily you only want to mess with the focus rectangle.  All you have to do is convince the control that it should not show it.  That's very easy, add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

class MyCheckBox : CheckBox {
    protected override bool ShowFocusCues {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Comment: As usual very helpful and interesting.. Curious: while you gave away the easy solution I was tinkering with an `override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)` method, which at least _seems_ to work fine. I found it hard to get the necessary `CheckBoxState` for the the CheckBox without a tedious series of checks; is there a more direct conversion? - Also: What are the pitfalls of using this way (by two calls to `CheckBoxRenderer` and one `DrawString`) ? (Always assuming that `CheckBoxRenderer` is available.. But hey its almost 2015..  ;-))

Comment: Well, replacing "very elaborate" code is indeed tedious :)